# Using COUNT returns different results

Tags: mysql

I am querying a table in my database to;

1. Determine the latest video_seek value
2. Return the total rows

I'm no expert with SQL and I cannot work out why using COUNT in a SQL statement returns different results compared to a statement that does not use COUNT.

---

Query:

```
SELECT video_seek, COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM videos 
WHERE video_id = 1 
  AND video_seek > 0 
  AND video_seek_end > 0 
ORDER BY video_seek DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Returns:

```
video_seek = 6012
total      = 199
```

---

Query:

```
SELECT video_seek 
FROM videos 
WHERE video_id = 1 
  AND video_seek > 0 
  AND video_seek_end > 0 
ORDER BY video_seek DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Returns:

```
video_seek = 7098
```

---

The total is correct but the video_seek is not and I do not know why the result is different depending on whether COUNT is used.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you used `COUNT(*)` you also need to `GROUP BY video_id` or your primary key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [MySQL peculiarity](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html). If you were using any other DBMS you'd be getting a 'missing GROUP BY expression' syntax error.

[COUNT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) is an aggregate function, what means that it combines several rows into one. If you don't have a `GROUP BY` clause that means you want to combine all matching rows into one, thus it doesn't make any sense to show values from an individual row. As I said, other database engines would just warn you about the error; MySQL, instead, simply picks data from an **arbitrary row** (not even a random row).

I know nothing about your data or business logic but...

```
SELECT MAX(video_seek) AS max_video_seek, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM videos
WHERE video_id = 1
AND video_seek > 0
AND video_seek_end > 0
```

*(Please note SQL code accepts line breaks.)*

Comment: I tried using GROUP BY as suggested by other answers but that did not work - the same result was returned. However using MAX() seemed to do the trick. Thank you!

Comment: Please don't just paste code you find in forums until code doesn't crash. It's important that you actually understand answers. You would use `GROUP BY` if you wanted to have **several groups** (e.g., get the max and count for each category).

Comment: I understand what you're saying and I thank you for your help. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use GROUP BY for count to get right solutions