# Count(*) returns different results at each execution

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin-4

**Please note**: this question is about PostgreSQL and pgAdmin4, so it is not a duplicate of [Using COUNT returns different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35792640/using-count-returns-different-results), which is about MySQL.

---

I have a ~4,000,000 records table. The following SQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM log LIMIT 40000)a WHERE some_column = true
```

returns a different value each time I execute it. What is the problem and how could I fix it?

Comment: what about dropping the subquery `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM log WHERE some_column = true LIMIT 40000` ?

Comment: @MartinGergov - this counts *all* the records in table that satisfies the condition (3442) so even if I try something like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM log WHERE some_column = true LIMIT 100` I still get 3442.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT * FROM log LIMIT 40000)a
WHERE some_column = true
```

The subquery is returning an *arbitrary* set of 40,000 rows.  This set is different each time you execute the query.  If you want a canonical set, you need `ORDER BY` with unique sorting keys.

You are filtering afterwards, so the number that match your condition is arbitrary.

If you want an arbitrary set of 40,000 rows where the condition is true, simply do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT l.*
      FROM log
      WHERE some_column = true
      LIMIT 40000
     ) ;
```

If you want a *random* set of 40,000 rows, you can do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT l.*
      FROM log
      WHERE some_column = true
      ORDER BY random() 
      LIMIT 40000
     ) ;
```

Arbitrary <> random.  (Note:  this is expensive; there are cheaper ways to get a random set.).

If you want a repeatable sample, well, there are various methods to do that.  One is to sort by something like a unique id and take the first 40,000 rows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT l.*
      FROM log l
      WHERE some_column = true
      ORDER BY primary_key
      LIMIT 40000
     ) ;
```

This is not a *random* sample, just a *repeatable* sample.

Comment: Thank you! It seems that the second example counts all the records in the table that satisfies the condition (3442) so even if I try something like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM log WHERE some_column = true ORDER BY random() LIMIT 100` I still get 3442.

Comment: @Sipo . . . All those queries require a subquery (I fixed that).  You are using `COUNT(*)`, not just counting the number of rows being returned.  The `LIMIT` is applied after the `COUNT(*)` is calculated, so the `LIMIT` needs to go into a subquery.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, i like your answer, i have just doubt, is there possible get last_insert_id and insert into another table in the same mysql query

Comment: @KrishnaJonnalagadda . . . This question is about sampling in Postgres.  I have no idea what your comment refers to.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, i am not asking related to postgres, I'm asking in general